# Code for UICollectionView in creating a News feed on a mobile app

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I am a beginner at coding and I want to learn to design an iOS mobile app. I am learning by recreating apps already built through watching Youtube. I am currently recreating Facebook News feed. Below is the custom code I've learned. I'm stuck on the part where we build the cells and the sizes of them. Specifically, I am getting an error on: collectionView?.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId). It seems this was viable statement in previous Swift version but not for 3.0. Thank you for anyones help!

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

let cellId = "cellId"

class FeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Facebook Feed"


    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)

    collectionView?.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
}

func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)



}
}

class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews()  {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 5):

As you are creating a custom collectionView cell you must use "collectionView.registerNib" instead of collectionView.registerClass.

```
collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Your Nib Name", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Your Cell Identifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

**To add a cell right click anywhere you want to add the file:**

[image]

**Choose a Cocoa Touch Class**

[image]

**Choose class name and check also create xib file then next**

[image]

**finally**

Try replacing this line:

```
collectionView?.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

with

```
collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "fileName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

the "fileName" is your xib file name.

Comment: Thank You for the above help!! I put the code in exactly and got an error code on the AppDelegate.swift section:

Comment: It was class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: do you have an .xib file for the cell?

Comment: This might sound like elementary but I don't. What is a .xib file and why is it needed? I was following the tutorial and learning that way.

Comment: the tutorial  is based off previous versions of Xcode in 2015-2016.

Comment: Yes, the above answer did help. However, now there aren't 3 Cells as coded in the above code. There are suppose to be 3 individual cells:(override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3.